# Unable to connect to websocket server over https from JavaScript client

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, webrtc

I have created websocket server for my webrtc app using the following code

```
 const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('C:/.../key_store.key'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('C:/.../key_store.crt')
};

var server = https.createServer(options, (req, res) => { res.writeHead(200); res.end('hello world\n');}).listen(9090);



//require our websocket library
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;

//creating a websocket server at port 9090 
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server});
```

My websocket client code is :

```
conn = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:9090');
```

I am getting the following exception in JavaScript console when I am trying to connect to websocket server using the above code:

> VM908:35 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response

I tried importing certificates in chrome but with no success.

Comment: Haven't you tried to use `wss://` instead of `ws://`?

Comment: I tried i got another error  'WebSocket connection to 'wss://139.126.123.18:9090/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE'

Answer (score 2):

WebRTC requires https and https pages allow Secure Wecsockets (wss) connections only.

So you need to create WebSocket in the client side as follows

```
conn = new WebSocket("wss://your_server_ip:wss_port/");
In your case:
conn = new WebSocket("wss://139.126.123.18:9090/");
```

I think you are using self signed SSL certificates(key_store.crt/.key) in your WebSocket Server.
In that case browsers will raise `ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE` exception for those connections.
So we have add exception manually by accessing that url in browser as following.

Open `https://139.126.123.18:9090/` in new tab,
Then click on Advanced -> proceed (for Chrome).

Or you can export your self signed CA to browsers.

Now your Secure WebSocket should get connected.

Comment: I used wss in client and kept websocket server with https but still its giving me NavigatorUserMediaError {name: "PermissionDeniedError", message: "Only secure origins are allowed.", constraintName: ""}

Comment: Your webpage url should be https. Print window.location in that error log.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your code to something like this

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');
const options = {
    key : fs.readFileSync('C:/.../key_store.key'),
    cert : fs.readFileSync('C:/.../key_store.crt')
};
var server = https.createServer(options).listen(9090);
//require our websocket library
var WebSocketServer = require('ws').Server;
//creating a websocket server at port 9090
var wss = new WebSocketServer({server});

// wait for connection to be established
wss.on('connection', (ws, req) => { 

    // send some message
    ws.send('hello world\n');

    // close connection
    ws.close(); 
});
```

Comment: Still no change same error "WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:9090/' failed: Connection closed before receiving a handshake response"

Comment: @user1188867 have you checked your certificate is ok?