# Chrome microphone permission

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, webrtc, voip

I'm working on a VOIP application using node js and webrtc. I'm having a problem with microphone being denied on start by chrome when I change IP from localhost to 192.168.....

When I start my application on localhost, it worked well on chrome & firefox, but when I start it on my PC's IP, it only works on firefox. Could this be due to my server working on HTTP not HTTPS?

Thank you!

Comment: Have you checked your browser's permissions? It might be set to deny external mic requests for security reasons. Have you tried different browsers?

Comment: Yes, it works on firefox, I allowed any settings that got to do with microphone permissions. : ( I really want it to run on chrome, so I can make a webview and run it on android.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes you need to use HTTPS.

> Starting with Chrome 47, getUserMedia() requests are only allowed from secure origins: HTTPS or localhost.

See [post](https://webrtchacks.com/chrome-secure-origin-https/) and [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44785684/3563200).